# Convert SQL Dates to standard format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert this type of date:

```
08Feb2008 0:00:00.000
```

I've looked and found how to convert to that type of date but I need it to be:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

I've tried the standard Convert to 102 type of options but they didn't work.

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: Do some string manipulation before conversion

Comment: You didn't say whether you are trying to convert text to datetime or datetime to text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to date first, then to string:

```
declare @s varchar(25)

SET @s = '08Feb2008 0:00:00.000'

print convert(varchar(10),convert(datetime, @s), 101)
```

Comment: Thanks threw this into the select line and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @strdate varchar(32) = '08Feb2008 0:00:00.000'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(@strdate,3,3,'/'+STR(CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@strdate,3,3),'   JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC')/3,2)+'/'),103)
```

2008-02-08 00:00:00.000